# In VBscript I am getting a type mismatch error when trying to split each item in an array list into a single array

Tags: arrays, arraylist, split, vbscript

I have an array list with each item being a string with spaces. I am iterate through the array list and split each item by it's space and add each one as an item in another array. I am getting a type mismatch but I can't figure out why. Here is the code.

```
Dim arrlist
Set arrlist = createobject("system.collections.arraylist")
Dim sArray(11)

arrlist.add("one two three four five six")
arrlist.add("Seven eight nine ten eleve twelve")

For i = 0 to arrlist.count - 1  

sArray = split(arrlist(i))

Next
```

Comment: Is this really vbscript, or is it trying to write vb.net (`system.collections.arraylist`)  as if we were still in the bad old pre-.net days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the declaration of your variable.

`Dim sArray(11)`

If you remove the `(11)` this works just fine

```
Dim arrlist
Set arrlist = createobject("system.collections.arraylist")
Dim sArray

arrlist.add("one two three four five six")
arrlist.add("Seven eight nine ten eleve twelve")

For i = 0 to arrlist.count - 1  
    sArray = split(arrlist(i))
Next
```